# Which method to pick for the Dictionary element look-up by key?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I was wondering, speed-wise which of the following methods is more preferable?

```
//Dictionary dic<string, int>;

int getElementByKey1(string key)
{
    if(dic.ContainsKey(key))     //Look-up 1
        return dic[key];     //Look-up 2 in case of a "hit"

    return null;
}

int getElementByKey2(string key)
{
    try
    {
        return dic[key];      //Single look-up in case of a "hit"
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;          //Exception in case of a "miss"
    }
}
```

Comment: Marcin gave a great solution to your question. I just want to make a side note that it is always a bad idea to use try/catch for decision making since it is a lot slower. Only use try/catch to catch unexpected exceptions.

Comment: @Quintium: Is the use of the `try/catch` block what makes it slow, or it becomes slow only when exception is thrown?

Comment: @ahmd0 Only when exception is actually thrown.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Thanks again. Just from curiosity, how much "waste" are we talking about in case of a thrown exception?

Comment: @ahmd0 - Yes, sorry for coming thru that it is always slow. No, it is as Marcin said, only when thrown. But as an example, it is better to check again NULL if you know there is a chance, than catch a NullException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the third one, using [`TryGetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) method:

```
int getElementByKey3(string key)
{
    int value;
    dic.TryGetValue(key, out value)
    return value;
}
```

By the way: your methods are invalid, because you can't return `null` from method declared as `int`.

It should be declared as `int?` instead to allow `null` value:

```
int? getElementByKey3(string key)
{
    int value;
    if(dic.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        return value;

    return null;
}
```

I think it would be the best one. But if I had to choose from you two suggested methods I would choose the first one - second looks faster, but when Exception will be thrown it wan't be that fast, because it has to be handled, and it requires some amount of work.

Comment: Oh very nice. I didn't realize such method exists. Much appreciated. (PS. I didn't realize in my original post that `int` cannot be `null`... oops.)

Answer (score 1):

You can test the execution time using [StopWatchers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), first, put some values on the Dictionary:

```
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        d.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), r.Next());

        //put some manual key for search later
        if (i == 9001)
            d.Add("it's over", 9000);
    }
```

And then, make some search using StopWatchers(using System.Diagnostics):

- First test, when the values exists (without throwing the exception):

  ```
  Stopwatch st1 = new Stopwatch();
  st1.Start();
  int getKey1 = getElementByKey1("it's over");
  st1.Stop();

  Stopwatch st2 = new Stopwatch();
  st2.Start();
  int getKey2 = getElementByKey2("it's over");
  st2.Stop();
  ```

Result in my pc:

```
Time spent on first search: 00:00:00.0002738
Time spent on second search: 00:00:00.0001169
```

So, the first is slower because the verification `if (d.ContainsKey(key))` before returning the value.

- Second test, when the values not exists (throwing the exception, e.g: `int getKey1 = getElementByKey1("nevermind");`):

Results:

```
Time spent on first search: 00:00:00.0002331
Time spent on second search: 00:00:00.0822669
```

As you can see, throw [exceptions](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/exceptions.html) [kills](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/exceptions2.html) [performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/09/25/771142.aspx) when the exception is thrown.

Note: you can't return null on a method that return int, so I used `return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

None. Better go with:

```
string result = null;
if (dic.TryGetValue(key, out result)
{
    // don't know, maybe log it somewhere or sth?
}

return result;
```